# How to tell flutter that a nullable variable is never null

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

```dart
Consumer<Cart>(
            builder: (_, cart, ch) => Badge(
              child: ch,
              value: cart.itemCount.toString(),
            ),
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.shopping_cart,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(CartScreen.routeName);
              },
            ),
          )
```

The child property of the builder is Widget. Meanwhile, the type of the `ch` parameter is `Widget?`.

I want to tell flutter that `ch` will never be null and it should always consider it as a widget. How do I do that?

Comment: I suggest reading about null-safety: https://dart.dev/codelabs/null-safety . But in short, you can use the `!` operator to force Dart into thinking a given value are never `null`. Be aware that your application will crash in case the value are `null` since Dart don't fully trust you and therefore inserts a runtime check ;) . So `child: ch!`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really get what you want. The ch from `Provider()` expects a `widget` type correct so how about

```
//it's never going to be null unless you say so
Widget ch(){
//return something 
return Container();
}
Consumer<Cart>(
            builder: (_, cart, ch) => Badge(
              child: ch(),
              value: cart.itemCount.toString(),
            ),
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.shopping_cart,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(CartScreen.routeName);
              },
            ),
          )
```